# Error: Cannot create self link for class

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I am getting below mentioned error when trying to access records from DB using a spring-data-jpa and spring-data-rest.

> Cannot create self link for class [Ljava.lang.Object;! No persistent
>   entity found!

[image: Tables Relation Diagram]

I am using below query to retrieve information and my Class structure is somewhat as below

```
Agency
@OneToMany(mappedBy="agencyCode",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JsonIgnore
List<Location> locations;


Location:
@ManyToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "zipCode")
Set<Zip> zips;

Zip:
@Id
@Column(name="zipCode")
String zipCode;
```

Query used to retrieve information is as below:

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT a, l.contactInfo.address.city, l.contactInfo.address.street,    l.contactInfo.phone from Agency a, Location l INNER JOIN  l.zips z where a.ceID = l.agencyCode and z.zipCode = :zip")
public List<Agency> findAgencyByZip(@Param("zip") String zip);
```

Any Help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Regards
Chetan

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace? Looks like a version compatibility problem between different jars/libs.

Comment: @mp911de : I am not sure how do i post the stack trace since its not allowing me to put it in the comments section

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is the cause, but in `Location`, for `@ManyToMany` you need a `@JoinTable` instead of `@JoinColumn`. Fix that, and maybe this error will also be fixed. Try this:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "LOCATION_ZIP", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "LOCATION_LOC_CODE"),
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ZIPS_ZIP_CODE")
Set<Zip> zips;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but this doesn't works may be some issue with the SDR or SDP itself, raised a ticket with spring lets see what they come up with https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-425